# High execution time of LCS length program in Python2

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x, time-limit-exceeded, dynamic-programming

I was trying to solve the [Longest Common Subsequence problem on a HackerRank exercise](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/common-child). 
It's quite simple and straightforward, just print out the length of the LCS. I submitted this code:

```
s1 = raw_input()
s2 = raw_input()

lcs = [[0 for j in xrange(len(s2)+1)] for i in xrange(len(s1)+1)]
for i, x in enumerate(s1):
    for j, y in enumerate(s2):
        if x == y:
            lcs[i+1][j+1] = lcs[i][j] + 1
        else:
            lcs[i+1][j+1] = max(lcs[i+1][j], lcs[i][j+1])

print lcs[-1][-1]
```

I think the logic is fine. The maximum string length is 5000. The problem is with the execution time. Some test cases take more than 10 seconds and the program terminates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like a classic LCS solution to me.

If all you want is to read the bottom-right element of the tableau, you don't actually have to store the entire matrix: all you need to keep is the most recent row.  That could save you a few megabytes of memory — I don't know how much processing time that would save, though.

To initialize the arrays, you can use the `*` operator instead of a list comprehension.  The indexing would be a bit less awkward, in my opinion, if you enumerated starting from 1.  I suggest `c1` and `c2` for characters out of `s1` and `s2`, respectively, but that's a matter of personal taste.

```
def lcs_len(s1, s2):
    prev_lcs = [0] * (len(s2) + 1)
    curr_lcs = [0] * (len(s2) + 1)
    for c1 in s1:
        curr_lcs, prev_lcs = prev_lcs, curr_lcs
        for j, c2 in enumerate(s2, 1):
            curr_lcs[j] = (
                1 + prev_lcs[j - 1] if c1 == c2 else
                max(prev_lcs[j], curr_lcs[j - 1])
            )
    return curr_lcs[-1]
```

Comment: Nice solution @200_success ^^ It beats mine.

Comment: Yes, this did work for all the test cases. Some of the later test cases that were previously getting timed out were computed in close to 10 seconds, but less than 10, so I could now get the entire challenge's results. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just one question - does using the `*` operator make the program execution faster than using list comprehension?

Comment: yes it does :) http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/127458/effective-python-2-3-two-dimensional-array-initialisation

Answer (score 2):

One way that I can think of, is getting rid of `lcs = [[0 for j in xrange(len(s2)+1)] for i in xrange(len(s1)+1)]` which uses 2 `for()` loops.

Let's use just one instead:

```
string1 = input()
string2 = input()

len_string1 = len(string1)
len_string2 = len(string2)

matrix = [[0] * 5001 for i in range(5001)]
for i in range(0, len_string1):
    for j in range(0, len_string2):
        if string1[i] == string2[j]:
            matrix[i + 1][j + 1] = matrix[i][j] + 1
        else:
            matrix[i + 1][j + 1] = max(matrix[i + 1][j], matrix[i][j + 1])
print(matrix[len_string1][len_string2])
```

As we just got rid off one `for` loop, the time complexity for your program would be improved. I also have checked / passed all the test cases from there.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) is also a nice article about LCS.

Comment: I've run the two different bits in timeit and the difference is striking.... 
7.54410600662s vs 1.76344299316s (10x repeat)